# VueJS use v-for variable as attribute value

Tags: vue.js, tabindex, v-for

I have an iterative loop that using `v-for` on an array of objects that then renders a html `li` item

```
<li class="block" v-for="(section, key) in sectionDetails">
    <a href="#" tabindex="{{ key }}">Item {{ key }}</a>
</li>
```

The problem here is that `key` in the `tabindex` attribute is not being rendered, what IS being rendered is `{{ key }}`.

How can I get the value of `key` to be used for `tabindex`? I've also tried, `:tabindex` but that gives me a Javascript error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Interpolation within attributes is not valid in Vue v2.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed)

You need to bind the `tabindex` attribute to the `key` like so:

```
<a href="#" :tabindex="key">Item {{ key }}</a>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/g5kefu2y/)